# HP MFP returns incorrect values ​via snmp protocol

Tags: snmp, network-printers

Good afternoon!

The HPLJ M776 and HPLJ M775 MFPs return incorrect snmp values ​​for the number of printed pages in color and black and white pages.

Following this page https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.4.1.2, the OID here below should count the total printed pages, but those do not refer as the counter on the `Usage Page` on the web-interface of the printer.

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.4.1.2.6.0 - black
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.4.1.2.7.0 - color
```

But for other color MFPs, this oid works. I can't understand what is the reason.

Comment: You can contact the printer vendor for assistance. Very likely they have software bugs.

Comment: @Lex Li : No, because firmware revision are identical...

Comment: “firmware revision are identical” does not rule out "they have software bugs". Contact the vendor and that's your only option for such issues.